# Payfast Flask giving back a 400 Post Error

Tags: payfast

When I try to capture the notify_url I get POST /notify HTTP/1.1" 400 instead of 200

Any suggestions on what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

sloved my own problem:

Was trying to capture it as a request.json should have capture it as a request.form